# At what points of r in real number is f continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

[image]

Please have a look at the picture above. Do we really have such points? If that's the case, how do I prove it?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Two big hints:

1. If $x$ is a rational number, then there is a sequence $(x_i)$ of irrational numbers converging to $x$. Look at the sequence $(f(x_i))$...
2. If $x$ is an irrational number, take any sequence $(x_i)$ of rational numbers converging to $x$, and write each $x_i = n_i / m_i$. Then $m_i \to \infty$. What happens in this case? Now, if we take any sequence $(x_i)$ of (not necessarily rational) numbers, we can split it into two subsequences: one of rationals and one of irrationals. What happens now?

Let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: Your argument in the form of sequences is very nice. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Consider any non- zero $ x \in \mathbb{Q}$ s.t. $f(x) = \frac{1}{m}$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$

Then consider the sequence $(x_n)$, where if $x_n = x + 10^{-n} \sqrt{2}$
Then the $x_n$ are all irrational, and $x_n \rightarrow x$

However $f(x_n) = 0$ $\forall$  $n \in \mathbb{N}$, so we do not have continuity at $x$

For any irrational number, $y$ say, $f(y) = 0$. Take $\epsilon > 0$.

Then for any fixed $N > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$, consider the $p_{n_k} \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $y - 1 < \frac{p_{n_k}}{k} < y+1$ s.t. $\frac{p_{n_k}}{k}$ is in lowest terms and $0 < k \leq N$

Then let $\delta = \frac{1}{2} \min_{k \leq N}(| y - \frac{p_{n_k}}{k}|)$ This is positive as $y$ is irrational.

For any $x$ s.t. $|x - y| < \delta$:

If x irrational $|f(x) - f(y)| = |0 - 0| = 0 < \epsilon$

Else $|f(x) - f(y)| < |f(x)| < \frac{1}{N} < \epsilon$ as required, as by choice of $\delta$, no rational number x in our interval has denominator $\leq N$.

As "a little don" has pointed out below, the function does not have a good definition at $0$, so ignore my previous statement - now deleted - about continuity at $0$, which assumed $f(0)=0$

Comment: What is the value of the function at 0?

Comment: For some reason I assumed $f(0) = 0$, thanks for pointing that out.